# Z ~N(0,1), distribution of √t Z?

Tags: distributions, brownian-motion

If I have a variable Z that is normally distributed, Z~N(0,1), what would be the distribution of √t Z, t>=0?
Can I say the process Xt = √t Z is a Brownian Motion?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Operations_on_normal_deviates

Comment: You will want to distinguish a *single* random variable $Z$ from a *parameterized set* of random variables $(Z_t)$, all having a standard Normal distribution.  When $t$ lies within an interval of nonnegative real numbers, the set $(\sqrt{t}\,Z_t)$ enjoys many of the properties of Brownian Motion.  (To obtain Brownian Motion you need to make some additional assumptions about the multivariate distributions, such as the distribution of $(Z_t,Z_s)$ for $s\ne t.$)

Answer (score 1):

- $X_t = \sqrt t Z \sim N(0,t)$
- $X_t$ is not a Brownian Motion because its increments are not independent. For example $X_t−X_s$ is not independent from $X_s -X_r$, $\forall t>s>r$.